# Django Tastypie: PUT request returns status 204 but creates a new object instead of updating

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am writing unit tests for a resource created using Tastypie. Tests for create, read, and delete are working just fine, but every time I try to make a PUT request, a new Sample object is getting created in the database instead of updating the existing record even though the correct status code (204) is being returned.

Here is the failing test:

```
def test_user_can_update_own_sample(self):
    credentials = self.get_credentials()
    nt.assert_equal(Sample.objects.count(), 1)
    sample = self.deserialize(client.get('/tastyapi/v1/sample/1/',
                              authentication=credentials, format='json'))
    nt.assert_equal("Created by a test case", sample['description'])
    sample['description'] = "Updated by a test case"

    resp = client.put('/tastyapi/v1/sample/1/', data=sample,
                       authentication=credentials, format='json')

    self.assertHttpAccepted(resp)

    # The following test fails saying 2 != 1
    nt.assert_equal(Sample.objects.count(), 1)
```

Here is my model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    version = models.IntegerField()
    sesar_number = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True)
    public_data = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    collection_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_precision = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    rock_type = models.ForeignKey(RockType)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='+')
    location_error = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    location = models.PointField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    metamorphic_grades = ManyToManyField(MetamorphicGrade, through='SampleMetamorphicGrade')
    metamorphic_regions = ManyToManyField(MetamorphicRegion, through='SampleMetamorphicRegion')
    minerals = ManyToManyField(Mineral, through='SampleMineral')
    references = ManyToManyField('Reference', through='SampleReference')
    regions = ManyToManyField(Region, through='SampleRegion')
    group_access = generic.GenericRelation(GroupAccess)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Sample #' + unicode(self.sample_id)

class Meta:
    # managed = False
    db_table = u'samples'
    permissions = (('read_sample', 'Can read sample'),)
```

And here is the resource:

```
class SampleResource(VersionedResource, FirstOrderResource):
rock_type = fields.ToOneField("tastyapi.resources.RockTypeResource",
                              "rock_type")
user = fields.ToOneField("tastyapi.resources.UserResource", "user")
class Meta:
    queryset = models.Sample.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
    authorization = ObjectAuthorization('tastyapi', 'sample')
    excludes = ['user', 'collector']
    filtering = {
            'version': ALL,
            'sesar_number': ALL,
            'public_data': ALL,
            'collection_date': ALL,
            'rock_type': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            }
    validation = VersionValidation(queryset, 'sample_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the pk for the object is not being sent in the put. Tastypie by default will create a new object on PUT if it doesn't find the pk in the request data. 
(Check [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L2221)).

You don't show all your code so it's not possible to know for sure if the field sample_id is present in the request or no as you are putting the data retrieved by the get (on the test).

One other possible problem is that BigIntegerField is not being properly inspected by tastypie and is being treated as a Charfield. [Check this pull request](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/760).

So either use the fork mentioned or change the BigInteger or convert in the hydrate for the specific field the char value to a int value.

```
def hydrate_sample_id(self ,value):
    return long(value)
```

Comment: It was actually a problem with the code I hadn't shown. I had overridden the `save` method on the `Sample` model wherein I was incrementing the primary key (sample_id) without checking if the `save` method had been called for object creation or updation.